# How do I alert the user that multiple fields are left blank in an HTML form after clicking submit?

Tags: javascript, html

If the user leaves multiple fields blank, I want to let the user know which fields he left blank in one alert message after they click submit. How would I do this? Any help is appreciated!

Here is the HTML code:

```
<form id="contactform" action="">
    <label> Name
        <input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" maxlength="50" autofocus="autofocus" />
    </label>
    <label> Last Name
        <input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" maxlength="150" />
    </label>
    <label> Address
        <input name="address" type="text" id="address" maxlength="200" />
    </label>
    <label> Postcode
        <input name="postcode" type="text" id="postcode" maxlength="50" />
    </label>
    <label> City
        <input name="city" type="text" id="city" maxlength="100" />
    </label>
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick=" return validate()" />
<input type="reset" value="Clear" />
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
function validate() {


    var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
    var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname');
    var address = document.getElementById('address');
    var postcode = document.getElementById('postcode');
    var city = document.getElementById('city');

    if (firstname.value == "") {
        alert("Make sure the first name field is filled");
        return false;
    }

    if (lastname.value == "") {
        alert("Make sure the last name field is filled");
        return false;
    }
    if (address.value == "") {
        alert("Make sure the address field is filled");
        return false;
    }
    if (postcode.value == "") {
        alert("Make sure the post code field is filled");
        return false;
    }
    if (city.value == "") {
        alert("Make sure the city field is filled");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So does your code work right now? From what I can see, it returns a different alert for every issue. You want it all in one alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function validate() {
  var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
  var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname');
  var address = document.getElementById('address');
  var postcode = document.getElementById('postcode');
  var city = document.getElementById('city');
  var errMsg = "";

  if(firstname.value == "") {
    errMsg+="Make sure the first name field is filled\n";
  } 
  if(lastname.value == "") {
    errMsg+="Make sure the last name field is filled\n";
  } 
  if(address.value == "") {
    errMsg+="Make sure the address field is filled\n";
  } 
  if(postcode.value == "") {
    errMsg+="Make sure the post code field is filled\n";
  } 
  if(city.value == "") {
    errMsg+="Make sure the city field is filled\n";
  } 
  if(errMsg != "") {
    alert(errMsg);
    return false;
  }else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id = "contactform" action = "">
<label> Name 
<input name = "firstname" type = "text" id = "firstname" maxlength = "50" autofocus = "autofocus"/>
</label>
<label> Last Name
<input name = "lastname" type = "text" id = "lastname" maxlength = "150" />
</label>
<label> Address 
<input name = "address" type = "text" id = "address" maxlength = "200"/>
</label>
<label> Postcode 
<input name = "postcode" type = "text" id = "postcode" maxlength = "50" />
</label>
<label> City 
<input name = "city" type = "text" id = "city" maxlength = "100" />
</label>
</form>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit" onclick = " return validate()" />
<input type = "reset" value = "Clear" />
```

This should do it, would need to format it how you like. Also there are several libs out there that handle this for you eg. http://formvalidation.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML validation, i.e. the `[required]` attribute:

```html
<form id="contactform" action="">
<label> Name 
<input required name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" maxlength="50" autofocus="autofocus"/>
</label>
<label> Last Name
<input required name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" maxlength="150">
</label>
<label> Address 
<input required name="address" type="text" id="address" maxlength="200">
</label>
<label> Postcode 
<input required name="postcode" type="text" id="postcode" maxlength="50">
</label>
<label> City 
<input required name="city" type="text" id="city" maxlength="100">
</label>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable and add the validation messgae to that and display it.A sample

```js
function validate() { 

var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname');
var address = document.getElementById('address');
var postcode = document.getElementById('postcode');
var city = document.getElementById('city');

var text = "Make sure";
var valid = true;

if(firstname.value == "") {
      text+= " the first name  ";
      valid = false;
 } 

if(lastname.value == "") {
       text += ( !valid ? '& ' : '')+ " the last name " 
      valid = false;
        
 } 
if(address.value == "") {
      text += ( !valid ? '& ' : '')+  " the address ";
      valid = false;
       
  } 
if(postcode.value == "") {
      text += ( !valid ? '& ' : '')+  " the postcode ";
      valid = false;
  } 
if(city.value == "") {

       text += ( !valid ? '& ' : '') + " the city ";
      valid = false;
       
        
     } 
     
     if(!valid){
        text+= " is Filled";
        alert(text);
        return false;
     }
   return true;
}
```

```html
<form id = "contactform" action = "">
<label> Name 
<input name = "firstname" type = "text" id = "firstname" maxlength = "50" autofocus = "autofocus"/>
</label>
<label> Last Name
<input name = "lastname" type = "text" id = "lastname" maxlength = "150" />
</label>
<label> Address 
<input name = "address" type = "text" id = "address" maxlength = "200"/>
</label>
<label> Postcode 
<input name = "postcode" type = "text" id = "postcode" maxlength = "50" />
</label>
<label> City 
<input name = "city" type = "text" id = "city" maxlength = "100" />
</label>
</form>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit" onclick = " return validate()" />
<input type = "reset" value = "Clear" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the blank fields in a string, like this:

```js
function validate() {


  var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
  var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname');
  var address = document.getElementById('address');
  var postcode = document.getElementById('postcode');
  var city = document.getElementById('city');
  var missedFields = ""
  if (firstname.value == "") {
    missedFields += "First name.\n";
    //alert("Make sure the first name field is filled");
    //return false;
  }

  if (lastname.value == "") {
    missedFields += "Last name.\n";
    //alert("Make sure the last name field is filled");
    //return false;
  }
  if (address.value == "") {
    missedFields += "Adress.\n";
    //alert("Make sure the address field is filled");
    //return false;
  }
  if (postcode.value == "") {
    missedFields += "Post code.\n";
    //alert("Make sure the post code field is filled");
    //return false;
  }
  if (city.value == "") {
    missedFields += "City.\n";
    //alert("Make sure the city field is filled");
    //return false;
  }

  if (missedFields.length > 0) {
    alert("Complete all fields:\n" + missedFields);
    return false
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form id="contactform" action="">
  <label> Name 
<input name = "firstname" type = "text" id = "firstname" maxlength = "50" autofocus = "autofocus"/>
</label>
  <label> Last Name
<input name = "lastname" type = "text" id = "lastname" maxlength = "150" />
</label>
  <label> Address 
<input name = "address" type = "text" id = "address" maxlength = "200"/>
</label>
  <label> Postcode 
<input name = "postcode" type = "text" id = "postcode" maxlength = "50" />
</label>
  <label> City 
<input name = "city" type = "text" id = "city" maxlength = "100" />
</label>
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick=" return validate()" />
<input type="reset" value="Clear" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way that you could do it - adding to a single alert string:

```
function validate() {

var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname');
var address = document.getElementById('address');
var postcode = document.getElementById('postcode');
var city = document.getElementById('city');
var alertstring = "Make sure all fields are filled! Currently missing:"

if(firstname.value == "") {
    alertstring += " -First Name-"
    } 

if(lastname.value == "") {
    alertstring += " -Last Name-"
    } 

if(address.value == "") {
    alertstring += " -Address-"
    } 

if(postcode.value == "") {
    alertstring += " -Postal Code-"
    } 
if(city.value == "") {
    alertstring += " -City-"
    } 
if(alertstring == "Make sure all fields are filled! Currently missing:") 
    {
        return true;
    }
else {
    alert(alertstring);
    return false;
    }
```

}